# How to describe response object in swagger, using yaml?

Tags: api, documentation, yaml, swagger

We have following json response for /papers/15

```
{
  "data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "foo"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "bar"
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "total": 15
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to describe it swagger yaml file?

Comment: first you need to validate your JSON - http://codebeautify.org/jsonvalidate

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I just figured out how to do this, in case somebody will need id.
Beside dedicated model definitions section ("definitions") it is possible to do inline model descriptions. Code above will looks like:

```
responses:
    "200":
      description: Matched Objects
      schema:
        type: object
        properties:
          data:
            type: object
            properties:
              authors:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: "#/definitions/object_with_id_and_title"
```

Comment: Could you show the entire response and definition please?

Comment: Where is the `meta` object and `total` property for that object?